# round float(x) to nearest .5 that is > x

Tags: r, plot, limit, rounding

I'm trying to make neat `xlim` and `ylim` values for a R plot. I want to: 1) round `xlim[2]` to the nearest multiple of 0.5 that is larger than the maximum value in the vector of values and 2) round `xlim[1]` to the nearest multiple of 0.5 that is smaller than the minimum value in the vector of values.

E.g.

```
x <- c(1.2, 2, 3.4)
y <- c(0.7, 2, 3.7)

# The desired lim values are then
xlim <- c(1, 3.5)
ylim <- c(0.5, 4)
plot(x, y, xlim= xlim, ylim= ylim)
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Thanks for the solutions! Both work very fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xlim <- c(floor(min(x) * 2) / 2, 
          ceiling(max(x) * 2) / 2)
# [1] 1.0 3.5

ylim <- c(floor(min(y) * 2) / 2, 
          ceiling(max(y) * 2) / 2)
# [1] 0.5 4.0
```

The trick is to multiply by 2 before rounding. The resulting values are then divided by 2.

Comment: min() instead of x[1], max() instead of tail is probably desired?

Comment: @tonytonov Agreed. My solution was limited to ordered vectors. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`pretty` will compute these values, and you can use `range` to select the end points,

```
range(pretty(x))
[1] 1.0 3.5
range(pretty(y))
[1] 0.5 4.0
```

Comment: `pretty` does't actually answer the OP's question of rounding to the nearest .5. `range(pretty(c(1.4,23.1)))` is `[1] 0 25`. Of course these might be "better" limits than 1 and 23.5, but they are not the limits the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

R package "base" has function  for making neat values - it is "pretty".

Consider using this code:
range(pretty(x)) or
range(pretty(y))

Comment: I suspect that this was downvoted because it is the same as James answer.

Comment: No problem, for easy qustions, there is always more people answering at the same time ....